# Rails Internacionalization datagrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datagrid, internationalization, rails-i18n

I install gem datagrid but cant translate this in i18n method or internacionalization
[image]

I cant make this can anyone help me?

Comment: i need to translate association, that has_many associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
class PatientsInnsGrid

  include Datagrid

  scope do
    Patient.includes(:plan)
  end

  filter(:name, :string, :header => "Nome") {|value, scope| scope.where("name ilike '%#{value}%'")}
#  filter(:created_at, :date, :range => true)

  column(:name, :header => "Nome") do |asset|
  format(asset.name) do |value|
    content_tag(:strong, value)
  end
end
  column_names_filter(:header => "Filtrar Colunas", :checkboxes => true)
  column(:created_at, :header => "Tempo Liminar") do |model3|
    model3.admission + model3.days_auth
  end
#  column(:created_at, :header => "Tempo Plano") do |model3|
#    model3.admission + model3.plan_time
#  end
  column(:plan, :header => "Plano") do |model2|
    model2.plan.nickname
  end
  column(:admission, :header => "Adimissão")
  column(:born, :header => "Data de Nascimento")
  column(:companion, :header => "Acompanhante") do
    companion? ? "Sim" : "Não"
  end
  column(:days_auth, :header => "Dias Autorizados")
  column(:process, :header => "Processo")
  column(:rod, :header => "Vara")
  column(:police, :header => "Apólice")
  column(:observation, :header => "Observações")
#  column(:created_at) do |model|
#    model.created_at.to_date
#  end
end
```